# VBA Excel 2010 function to make cell calculations then sum using different ranges

Tags: function, excel, for-loop, excel-2010, vba

I am trying to write a function that will determine the total basal area in square feet in a cell by summing the individual calculations for tree diameters in varying numbers in the range of adjacent cells.

I am new to VBA and I keep getting errors, that I can't seem to find examples and answers online. My Spreadsheet cell using this just returns a #VALUE in the cell.

```
Function BArange(x As Range)
    Dim BArangeTot As Double
    BArangeTot = 0

    Dim y As Integer
    y = x.Count

    Dim BArangei As Integer
    BArangei = 0

    For i = 1 To y
        BArangei = 0.005454154 * x(1, i) ^ 2
        BArangeTot = BArangeTot + BArangei
    Next i

    Return

    MsgBox (BArangeTot)

End Function

Function BA(x As Double)
    BA = 0.005454154 * x ^ 2
End Function
```

To describe the canopy occupancy of a site we calculate the cross sectional area of trees at a 4.5-foot height often in spreadsheets, and we need to sum up multiple stemmed trees as well. The number of square feet of basal area per acre is a very standard metric of density/occupancy of a site. I thought defining a function that we could use for this would be handy.

I have spent several hours on this and tried using the Set command to initiate my variables but I think that is only necessary if they are objects. I have tried commenting out lines and running the program to my curser point in the program, but I don't get anything I can look up as similar examples answers. My lastest problem was it expecting sub, function, or property.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this as a standard Excel formula.

If your data is in `A1:A10`

`=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A10,A1:A10)*0.005454154`

Answer (score 2):

A few corrections I sugest:

1. If `x` is a `Range`, if you want to read the values of the cells, you need to write this:

   ```
   x.Cells(1,i)
   ```

   or

   ```
   x.Cells(1,i).Value
   ```

   (I prefer the second option)
2. If you want to return a value, you need to do an assignment to the function name:

   ```
   BArange = BArangeTot
   ```
3. Also, I infer that your range is a column, so I would assign the `y` variable as follows:

   ```
   y = x.Rows.Count
   ```
4. Finally, delete the `Return`.

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks, I should have made BArangei as Double not Integer, and the range is adjacent columns so y=x.Columns.Count worked. I removed the return and MsgBox(BArangeTot). I added BArange=BArangeTot. Problem solved. Brad